# Postfix after-queue content filter

Tags: postfix, spf, mailing-list, return-path

I am running a postfix/dovecot/spamassassin/clamav system on Debian 10 with Postfix 3.5.13 for my domains. One domain has a small private mailing list. If someone writes to the list postfix prepends the header
`Return-Path:` 
containing the original posters address to all outgoing mails. Remote receiving mail servers complain about SPF mismatch because they check the domain in Return-Path header against the name of the mail server in my SPF DNS record. I compared to big mailing lists, they rewrite the Return-Path.
`header_checks =`  is not the solution because the header is prepended after header_checks.
I tried the postfix option
`message_drop_headers = bcc,content-length,resent-bcc`
but it is not removing the unwanted header and it would remove it for all outgoing mails not just for the mailing list receivers.
So I came up with the idea of rewriting the header in a post queue filter script. Is this the place of choice and how would the official postfix example

```
24 # Specify your content filter here.
25 # filter <in.$$ || {
26 #   echo Message content rejected; exit $EX_UNAVAILABLE; }
```

need to be customized to rewrite the Return-Path header?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well, isn’t your mailing list software handling this? It should rewrite headers like `Return-Path`, `Resent-From`, etc. Or what do you mean by small private mailing list?

Comment: I am using froxlor to manage my domains. That implements message forwarding to multiple external addresses but does not provide the means to rewrite the return-path header.